# Jacoco giving 0% coverage and Intellij Idea gives very less coverage

Tags: android, intellij-idea, code-coverage, jacoco

I am using android studio 3.5.3. After writing unit tests I made sure that unit tests are hitting most of the lines by debugging test cases but coverage is 11% which is very less for my case. Am getting these messages in ide

```
---- IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner ---- 
sampling ...
include patterns:
exclude patterns:Class transformation time: 0.854799694s for 3630 classes or 2.3548200936639117E-4s per class
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.LazyJavaPackageFragmentProvider: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.LazyJavaTypeParameterResolver$resolve$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.InlineClassesUtilsKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.SubpackagesScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.MemberDeserializer$getPropertyFieldAnnotations$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.deserialization.BinaryVersion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.SimpleType: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses$classes$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializedPackageFragmentImpl$initialize$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.util.OperatorChecks$checks$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.PackageFragmentProviderImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.util.OperatorChecks$checks$2: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.util.OperatorChecks$checks$3: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.typeEnhancement.NotNullTypeParameter: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.typeEnhancement.SignatureEnhancementBuilder$ClassEnhancementBuilder$FunctionEnhancementBuilder: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.typeEnhancement.TypeEnhancementKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.TypeSignatureMappingKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.CompanionObjectMapping: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope$nestedClasses$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.annotations.Annotations$DefaultImpls: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.header.KotlinClassHeader$Kind: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.AnnotationDeserializer: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.typesApproximation.CapturedTypeApproximationKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.typeEnhancement.SignatureEnhancement$SignatureParts$extractQualifiersFromAnnotations$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.SignatureBuildingComponents: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.FakePureImplementationsProvider: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.KotlinTypeFactory: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.descriptorUtil.DescriptorUtilsKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.utils.ReportLevel$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope$kotlinScopes$2: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.types.RawSubstitution: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.components.JavaAnnotationDescriptor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInSerializerProtocol: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.BuiltinMethodsWithSpecialGenericSignature: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.DescriptorKindFilter$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.DeserializedDescriptorResolver: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.MappingUtilKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.typeEnhancement.SignatureEnhancementBuilder$ClassEnhancementBuilder: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeSubstitutionKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageScope$classes$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.ContextKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.calls.inference.CapturedTypeConstructor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaStaticClassScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassDescriptor$declaredParameters$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeCapabilitiesKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedSimpleFunctionDescriptor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.deserialization.ProtoTypeTableUtilKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.JvmTypeFactoryImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltInClassDescriptorFactory$cloneable$2: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.functions.BuiltInFictitiousFunctionClassFactory$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.AbstractBinaryClassAnnotationAndConstantLoader: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.ClassDeclaredMemberIndex: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.JavaIncompatibilityRulesOverridabilityCondition$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedPackageMemberScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtilsKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltIns: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.BuiltinSpecialProperties: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.FlexibleTypesKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.deserialization.TypeTable: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: au.com.orient.filelogger.FileLogger$$special$$inlined$sortBy$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.descriptorUtil.DescriptorUtilsKt$declaresOrInheritsDefaultValue$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.annotations.AnnotationDescriptor$DefaultImpls: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.deserialization.BinaryVersion$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.FunctionTypesKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.ReflectionTypes$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.header.KotlinClassHeader: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.BinaryClassAnnotationAndConstantLoaderImpl$loadAnnotation$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltInsSettings$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsInitializer: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$computeDescriptors$$inlined$let$lambda$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.sequences.SequencesKt___SequencesKt$asIterable$$inlined$Iterable$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$computeDescriptors$$inlined$let$lambda$3: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.BuiltInsLoader$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.VisibilityUtilKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.SpecialBuiltinMembers: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.typeUtil.TypeUtilsKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.renderer.DescriptorRendererModifier: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.util.capitalizeDecapitalize.CapitalizeDecapitalizeKt$decapitalizeSmart$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedPropertyDescriptor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.annotations.AnnotationUtilKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.SuspendFunctionTypesKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.MemberDeserializer: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.ErasedOverridabilityCondition: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.AnnotationAndConstantLoaderImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializedPackageFragmentImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.typeEnhancement.SignatureEnhancement: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.builtins.BuiltInsBinaryVersion$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializedClassDataFinder: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.utils.Jsr305State: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.ValueParameterDescriptorImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ProtoBasedClassDataFinder: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.KotlinTypeKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.utils.SmartSet$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope$constructors$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.ValueParameterDescriptorImpl$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageFragment$partToFacade$2: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.TypeParameterUtilsKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.PossiblyInnerType: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.annotations.CompositeAnnotations: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.MemberDeserializer$getAnnotations$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.JvmAnnotationNamesKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.renderer.DescriptorRendererImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.ModuleDescriptorImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.typeEnhancement.SignatureEnhancementKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.jvm.deserialization.ClassMapperLite: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.BinaryClassAnnotationAndConstantLoaderImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.ModuleDescriptorImpl$packageFragmentProviderForWholeModuleWithDependencies$2: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.metadata.jvm.deserialization.JvmNameResolver: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.AbstractTypeConstructor$supertypes$3: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsPackageFragmentImpl$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.ChainedMemberScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.MemberScopeImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassDescriptor$LazyJavaClassTypeConstructor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.kotlin.AbstractBinaryClassAnnotationAndConstantLoader$loadAnnotationsAndInitializers$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.typeEnhancement.Result: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.checker.TypeCheckerContext: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.name.FqNamesUtilKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaTypeParameterDescriptor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaPackageScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.utils.CollectionsKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.types.RawTypeImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltIns$settings$2$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltIns$settings$2$2: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.renderer.DescriptorRendererOptionsImpl$property$$inlined$vetoable$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.JvmPackageScope: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltInsSettings: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.LazyJavaResolverContext: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.components.JavaAnnotationMapper: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.util.capitalizeDecapitalize.CapitalizeDecapitalizeKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.util.Checks: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.BuiltinMethodsWithDifferentJvmName: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.FlexibleTypeImpl: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.checker.UtilsKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltInClassDescriptorFactory$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ClassDeserializer: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.typeEnhancement.PredefinedEnhancementInfoKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.descriptors.UtilKt: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedTypeParameterDescriptor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassDescriptor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassTypeConstructor: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializationComponents: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.AnnotationTypeQualifierResolver: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.utils.Jsr305State$description$2: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeConstructorSubstitution$Companion: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.util.NoDefaultAndVarargsCheck: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.TypeDeserializer$simpleType$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.LazyPackageViewDescriptorImpl$memberScope$1: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.constants.ConstantValueFactory: java.lang.Throwable
[2020.02.20 11:53:36] (Coverage): Class data was not extracted: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.functions.BuiltInFictitiousFunctionClassFactory: java.lang.Throwable
```

I am seeing that this happens when in unit test this code get hits :

```
            dirFiles?.apply {
                sortBy {
                    it.lastModified()
                }
                for ((i, prevFile) in withIndex()) {
                    if (i <= size - maxLogFileCount) {
                        Log.i("FileLogger", "Deleting log file  named $prevFile")
                        prevFile?.delete()
                    }
                }
            }
```

On other StackOverflow and other online material available online which are as old as 2017 says this is due to IntelliJ coverage tool issue (jacoco has the same issue) as they are not able to handle the inline functions. I just wanted to confirm if this issue is same as above in 2020. And if you have any solutions please let me know.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I did not checked it again.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow/comment the issue that is already opened for this problem at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27787

Comment: Yeah I raised a issue too: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FKT-36870

And it is marked similar to above issue. But no update on this issue for more than a year.

Comment: I have already commented on this issue but not sure when solution will be provided. I thought some of us might have a sustainable fix for this.